# Understanding FindBugs warning about Class doesn't override equals in superclass

Tags: java, intellij-idea, equals, hashcode

According to Josh Bloch in Java:

> There is no way to extend an instantiable class and add a value
>   component while preserving the equals contract, unless you are willing
>   to forgo the benefits of object-oriented abstraction

So here 's my case I had a class `Foo` that had overridden `equals()` and `hashcode()` as implemented by Intellij Idea . Now I have another class `FooChild` that extends `Foo` and adds a couple more fields to 'Foo`. Now FindBugs  is complaining about FooChild:

> Class doesn't override equals in superclass This class extends a class
>   that defines an equals method and adds fields, but doesn't define an
>   equals method itself. Thus, equality on instances of this class will
>   ignore the identity of the subclass and the added fields. Be sure this
>   is what is intended, and that you don't need to override the equals
>   method. Even if you don't need to override the equals method, consider
>   overriding it anyway to document the fact that the equals method for
>   the subclass just return the result of invoking super.equals(o).

My  question is "What is meant by **equality on instances of this class will
 ignore the identity of the subclass** ? I understand the part about ignoring the added fields since no `equals()` method has been written for them yet .

Comment: I fundamentally disagree with findbugs flag here. I can think of no logical reason that [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) should be overridden just because a field value is added in a subclass. In fact, doing that fundamentally breaks the equals contract. If you do what findbugs suggests your equals method is no longer symmetric (x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is meant by "equality on instances of this class will ignore the
>   identity of the subclass ?"

If class `Foo` has an `equals()` method, then `FooChild` inherits it, meaning that if you compare two instances of `FooChild` using `equals()`, the `Foo.equals()` method will be called.

If `FooChild` has any data members, then it's probably possible for two instances of `FooChild` to have the same values for members in their `Foo` parts, but different values for the members defined directly in the class. But the `Foo.equals()` method will only look at the members defined in `Foo`, and so would pronounce two such objects to be `equals()`, even though their `FooChild` parts are different.

This is why you need to override `equals()` in `FooChild`.

Now, what happens if you compare a `Foo` and a `FooChild` using `equals()`, when both classes have their own version of `equals()`? It depends which object you call `equals()` on, and it depends on how you implement the two `equals()` methods. Frankly, it's a mess! That's the meaning of the first quote, the one from Josh Bloch. It's impossible to define these two `equals()` methods so they always do the right thing. Therefore, it's best to avoid the situation where one value class (i.e., a class whose identity is tied up with the values of its member variables) extends another value class.

Comment: this is one of the reasons why composition should be preferred over inheritance . I think the he builders from the Apache Commons Lang library provides  a clean solution here . This is what I did in my case .

Comment: @Geek: Calling a library can't solve this problem because it's rooted in the contract of Object.equals(Object). Use composition instead of inheritance to ensure that you are comparing like with like.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you shouldn't be including any state coming from super classes when computing your `equals` or `hashCode` methods. That state is out of the scope of the class you are working on and your class should rely on the super class instead of rewriting its functionality.

When generating `equals` and `hashCode` with IntelliJ, if you want to include any computation from parent classes just make a small modification to the methods adding a call to `super.equals(o)` or `super.hashCode()`.

Another way of implementing those methods is to use the [`EqualsBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) and [`HashCodeBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) from the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library, those builders provide with semantics to add the super invocation.

**EDIT:**

Answering *"What is meant by equality on instances of this class will ignore the identity of the subclass?"*: As you already pointed out, it means that if you have two classes, one extending the other, and the subclass doesn't override neither `equals` or `hashCode`, then, when checking for two instances for equality (or adding to a hashed structure) both will behave as if they were from the same class. Here is an example:

```
class A {
   private int intField = 2;

   public A(int value) {
       intField = value;
   }

   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (null == o) return false;
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (!(o instanceof A)) return false;

       return intField == ((A) o).intField;
   }

   public int hashCode() {
       return 11 * intField;
   }
}

class B extends A {
   private boolean boolField = true;

   public B(int intValue, boolean boolValue) {
       super(intValue);
       boolField = boolValue;
   }

   // no equals or hashCode
}
```

So, with those classes you'll face the following:

```
A a = new A(12);
B b = new B(12, false);
b.equals(a);    // returns true
```

To avoid that, just add a super call inside `equals` or `hashCode` methods after generating them in IntelliJ.

```
class B extends A {
   private boolean boolField = true;

   public B(int intValue, boolean boolValue) {
       super(intValue);
       boolField = boolValue;
   }

   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (null == o) return false;
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (!(o instanceof B)) return false;
       if (!super.equals(o)) return false;

       return boolField == ((B) o).boolField;
   }

   public int hashCode() {
       int hash = super.hashCode();
       hash += 11 * Boolean.valueOf(boolField).hashCode();
       return hash;
   }

}
```

Other way, as I already said, is to use the builders from the Apache Commons Lang library.

Comment: the links to the builders already provide with examples how to use them

Comment: Thanks for those links . Can you answer my first question which is in bold ?

Comment: so your example means that it is not ignoring the identity of the subclass , it is just ignoring any significant fields that were added to itself . By *it" I meant subclass instance...

Comment: yeah, that's right, the identity of the class is different, as it is with two different instances of the same class. But `equals` is ment for *equality* rather than *identity* (which is done with the `==` operator). What actually happens is, since there is no specific implementation of `equals` in the child class, when looking for *equality* it will fall back into the `equals` method provided by the parent class, and that parent class doesn't know anything regarding the fields in any child class.

Comment: Sorry, but B.equals(Object) is broken because it breaks symmetry! This can't get solved as shown below.

Comment: what's the problem with symmetry? I want `b1.equals(b2)` if both are instances from the same class and have the same inner state, and `b2.equals(b1)` will also return the same value. What I don't want is `b.equals(a)` to return the same value as `a.equals(b)`, they are instances of different classes!!

Comment: Mind the general contract of Object.equals(Object)! If you ignore it, then it may break all applications which rely on it. For example, you couldn't use these objects as keys in a hash map (although you shouldn't use mutable keys in hash map anyway). As explained, this problem cannot get solved with inheritance - use composition instead.

Comment: you are right, I'm feeling how the world falling into pieces due to that. What you are pointing out is out of the scope of question and when building your domain model overriding `equals` wisely is not going to make the world explode, furthermore, is the recommended way. Composition is a different design pattern that should be used when you actually need ... (drumroll) composition!

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez +1 for pointing me to the Apache builders . It helped me here . But I thought the other answer from Ernest Friedman-Hill to be more precise . So accepted that one. Anyway thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach to deal with this kind of problem is to resort to composition rather than inheritance. This is necessary, because as Josh Block details in his excellent book "Effective Java", you can't really override an implementation of equals(Object) which considers properties without breaking the general contract of equals(Object).

Example:

```
class Foo {
    boolean property;

    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        return this == that
            || (that instanceof Foo)
                && this.property == ((Foo) that).property;
    }

    public int hashCode() { ... } // needs to be consistent with equals(Object).
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    boolean anotherProperty;

    // This is broken - DO NOT USE IT!
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        return super.equals(that)
            && (that instanceof Bar)
            && this.anotherProperty == ((Bar) that).anotherProperty
    }

    public int hashCode() { ... } // needs to be consistent with equals(Object).
}
```

Now why is the implementation of Bar.equals(Object) broken? Simply because it breaks symmetry! Here's the prove:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = new Bar();
assert foo.equals(bar); // passes because bar is a Foo and property is zero
assert bar.equals(foo); // throws up because foo isn't an instance of Bar!
```

This kind of problem cannot get solved using inheritance. You need to use composition.

As a consequence, it's often a good idea to declare the equals(Object) and hashCode() methods final when overriding them so that they can't get overridden again with a broken implementation.

Comment: marking `equals` and `hashCode` final?? why not marking the whole class as final? someone could override our methods and *break* the functionality of our parent class!!

Comment: As Joshua Bloch put it: "Design for inheritance or otherwise inhibit it!". In that sense, it may make sense to have the class open for inheritance but inhibit only overriding equals(Object) and hashCode() again.